# Android reporting wrong IP address

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get the local IP address of the device. When I login into the device using adb shell and run ifconfig, I get the following output:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:2653 TX bytes:2653



wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:4b:87:ff:dd:aa  Driver bcmsdh_sdmmc
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 TX bytes:458


eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:bb:cc:52:c9:29  Driver meson6-dwmac
          inet addr:192.168.144.25  Bcast:192.168.144.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2607:fb11:2:111:111:d791:5862:1bd7/64 Scope: Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::81a5:222:222:1956/64 Scope: Link
          inet6 addr: 2607:fb11:2:333:333:333:220e:ba3c/64 Scope: Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:202073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:62383835 TX bytes:2110461
          Interrupt:45
```

I'm trying to get the 192.168.144.25 address, but when I use the following method to get the IP address, it's reporting it wrong: 13.27.23.153

```
private fun getLocalIpAddress(): String? {
    var tag = "ipdebug"
    val networkInterfaces: Enumeration<NetworkInterface>
    try
    {
        networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
    }
    catch (ex: SocketException)
    {
        Log.d( tag, ex.toString())
        return null
    }

    while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        val networkInterface = networkInterfaces.nextElement()
        val inetAddresses = networkInterface.inetAddresses

        Log.d( tag, "### " + networkInterface.displayName )

        while (inetAddresses.hasMoreElements())
        {
            val inetAddress = inetAddresses.nextElement()
            Log.d( tag, "\t\t" + inetAddress.hashCode() + "\tipv4:" + (inetAddress is Inet4Address) + "\tloop:" + inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress )
            return inetAddress.hashCode()
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

When I dump all of the interfaces/IP's from the getLocalIPAddress method, I get 3 IP addresses:

```
### wlan0
### ip6tnl0
### ip_vti0
### lo
             1               ipv4:false      loop:true
             2130706433      ipv4:true       loop:true
### sit0
### eth0
             -1626538995     ipv4:false      loop:false    
             -1262694887     ipv4:true       loop:false
### ip6_vti0
### tunl0
```

But when I convert decimal to IP, I get the following:

```
 127.0.0.1
 96.243.3.243
 75.67.49.231
```

Is there any reason why the ifconfig IP does not match the IP reported by the NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()? Thank you!

Comment: what are you using to retrieve the ip address? `getAddress()` -> This returns the ip in network byte order and it might be possible that you need to convert them to devices byte order to get the right ip address. If you're just interested in the representation `getHostAddress()` returns the ip address already in text. I've also noticed you're returning `inetAddress.hashCode()` which is an int and not a String like your function declares. It's also not the ip address.